# Playing a QML animation more than once without using States

Tags: qt, animation, qml

I'm trying to get an QML animation to Start every time it's clicked, without using States. It Starts the first time it's clicked, but then won't Start when it's clicked a second time.
Is there a reason why? Here's the code I'm working it.

```
Image {
    id: head;
    source: "vlad.png";
    height: 80;
    width: 90;
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: animateHead.start();
        ParallelAnimation {
            id: animateHead;
            NumberAnimation {
                property int randomValueX: 0;
                function randomize(randomValueX) {
                    randomValueX = (Math.floor(Math.random()*210));
                    return randomValueX;
                }
                target: head;
                properties: "x";
                to: randomize(randomValueX);
                duration: 1000;
                easing {
                    type: Easing.OutBack;
                    overshoot: 5
                }
            }
            NumberAnimation {
                property int randomValueY: 0;
                function randomize(randomValueY) {
                    randomValueY = (Math.floor(Math.random()*210));
                    return randomValueY;
                }
                target: head;
                properties: "y";
                to: randomize(randomValueY);
                duration: 700;
                easing {
                    type: Easing.OutBack;
                    overshoot: 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the values of the `to` properties of the two `NumberAnimation` instances are bound only once during initialization of the QML component. They are not recalculated when you call `animateHead.start()` and animations are only executed if the value of the `to` property differs from the actual value of the animated property. That's why it works only the first time.

A working solution would be:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Image {
    id: head;
    source: "vlad.png";
    height: 80;
    width: 90;
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            xAnimation.to = Math.floor(Math.random()*210)
            yAnimation.to = Math.floor(Math.random()*210)
            animateHead.start();
        }
        ParallelAnimation {
            id: animateHead;
            NumberAnimation {
                id: xAnimation
                target: head;
                properties: "x";
                duration: 1000;
                easing {
                    type: Easing.OutBack;
                    overshoot: 5
                }
            }
            NumberAnimation {
                id: yAnimation
                target: head;
                properties: "y";
                duration: 1000;
                easing {
                    type: Easing.OutBack;
                    overshoot: 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the values of the `to` properties are set explicitly in the `onClicked` handler of the `MouseArea`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, because I was trying to solve similar problem, googled this question and decided that *there must be another way* of dealing with animated property initialization. In *Qt 5* you can use the `PropertyAction` to instantly initialize some properties.

Example from `PropertyAction` type documentation:

```
SequentialAnimation {
  PropertyAction { target: img; property: "opacity"; value: .5 }
  NumberAnimation { target: img; property: "width"; to: 300; duration: 1000 }
  PropertyAction { target: img; property: "opacity"; value: 1 }
}
```

I don't know how would it interact with `ParallelAnimation` but it works very good with `SequentialAnimation`.